# Querying timeline of events - DBpedia and SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am a beginner with SPARQL and DBPedia and I cannot find definitive answers to my question.

We have the following article on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Paris

This is a timeline of all the events that happened in Paris. The first event in the timeline is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Paris#Prehistory,_the_Parisii_and_the_Roman_Lutetia

What I want to do is to query all the events in this timeline. However, If I get the entry of "Timeline of Paris" on DBpedia [here](https://dbpedia.org/page/Timeline_of_Paris), I do not find the events listed in the wikipedia page. How can I get them ?

Comment: you can't - the data is just not contained in DBpedia - the reason for this is that there is no such extractor for simple HTML lists - or at least nothing officially used for the official DBpedia dumps. Most of the DBpedia data stems from the Wikipedia infoboxes for which it's rather simple to write mappings and extractors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comment by @UninformedUser, you can't do what you wish, because the data you want is not contained in DBpedia. Extractors for such HTML lists are not currently part of the DBpedia kit.

Most DBpedia data comes from the Wikipedia "infoboxes" for which it's fairly simple to write mappings and extractors. HTML lists and the like require more difficult programming efforts — and such efforts would be more than welcome if you wanted to [join the team of DBpedia volunteers](https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework/wiki).